# SSIS - Bulk Insert with Format File and Single Quotes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bulkinsert

I am using SQL Server 2014.

I am being supplied a csv file that has 3 columns (AddressLine columns below) that MAY contain values surrounded by single quotes....example...

```
Name, Age,  AddressLine1              ,  AddressLine3  ,    AddressLine3,  Job
Paul, 31 ,  '59, Reed Close'          ,  Ashby         ,    Essex       ,  Carpenter   
Jane, 39 ,  Bond Street               ,  Rochford      ,    Kent        ,  Nurse
Mary, 31 ,  'Tomb Lodge, Reeve  Close',  Poole         ,    Essex       ,  Football Player
Ian , 31 ,  66 Puffin Road            ,  'Maine, Kent,',    'Kent, UK'  ,  Policeman
```

I am tying to execute a SQL Server bulk insert statement using a format file...

The load is failing around the Address columns - probably an error in my format file.

```html
<RECORD>
    <FIELD ID ="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="255" />
    <FIELD ID ="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="255" />
    <FIELD ID ="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\',\'" MAX_LENGTH="100" />
    <FIELD ID ="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\',\'" MAX_LENGTH="100" />
    <FIELD ID ="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\',\'" MAX_LENGTH="50" />
    <FIELD ID ="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="15" />
  </RECORD>
```

Is there a way I can handle optional single quotes in the data in a format file or another way?

Comment: Have you tried using SSIS?

Comment: I am using using SSIS as a component of the solution. What I am now trying to is replace the single quotes in the file with double quotes (which I have done in SSIS) and will now modify the format file to for those columns that are now surrounded with double-quotes to be define in the format file as...   TERMINATOR "\",\""

Answer (score 1):

The problem is really your csv file having spaces.

If you format your csv like this:

```
Name,Age,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressLine3,Job
Paul,31,'59, Reed Close',Ashby,Essex,Carpenter   
Jane,39,Bond Street,Rochford,    Kent        ,  Nurse
Mary, 31 ,'Tomb Lodge, Reeve  Close',  Poole         ,    Essex       ,  Football Player
Ian , 31 ,  66 Puffin Road            ,'Maine, Kent,','Kent, UK',  Policeman
```

Then you can use text qualifier like this:

[image]

with results like this:

[image]